# AWS amplify cognito users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

There is any way to propagate the users from cognito to an aws amplify api? My main goal for this application is allow a `Todo` (created by a normal cognito user) to be accessed by other cognito users.

By default i will be only the one that has access to this `Todo`. I will be allowed to, eventually, add "members" to this todo.

After some research in the amplify docs, i have two approaches:
1 - Use a lambda trigger to create a model `User` using mutations from graphql. For this approach i don't believe i can access api services on lambda triggers from authentication;
2 - As soon as the user logins i will have a component (REACT component for instance, that will call a service that (1) will check if the user exists and (2) create the new user if not existing. This approach seems a bit odd as we will have two sources of truth.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Amazon Cognito together with AWS AppSync and DynamoDB, I believe the "GraphQL" API from the "Amplify" command line should do the trick.

In your model schema, you can generate fields with different ownership rules:

```
type Draft 
    @model 
    @auth(rules: [

        # Defaults to use the "owner" field.
        { allow: owner },

        # Authorize the update mutation and both queries. Use `queries: null` to disable auth for queries.
        { allow: owner, ownerField: "editors", operations: [update] }
    ]) {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String
    owner: String
    editors: [String]!
}
```

Here is the complete documentation: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql

I still haven't used the "auth" directive, but it seems for me it could be refined further to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all! Really helpful. I saw that documentation as well. However, one of the requirements of the application is to have information about which user has created the item and which members belong to that item. The latter part is the most problematic to me as i didn't see any solution from amazon to solve this kind of problem. Or at least, i was not able to find any documentation or code that support that heuristic.